# Rails filter hook for after a controller action has run, but before the view is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I've got a spree commerce 2.1.1 app (Rails 4.0.0), and I'm wanting to show some 'related products' on the products detail page. The related products will just be a random selection of products with the same brand / gender as the one being viewed. It's working... I've made `products_controller_decorator.rb`, which extends spree's `products_controller.rb`.

Spree's `products_controller.rb` has a before_filter which sets `@product`:

```
before_filter :load_product, :only => :show
```

and my own decorator has a method that sets `@related_products`

```
before_filter :get_related_products, :only => :show
```

The problem is:

a) As it happens, the `load_product` before filter gets called before my `get_related_products` before filter, so co-incidentally, I have access to the `@product` variable that it sets. But as far as I can see there's no guarantee of that happening. I want to be sure that my filter is called later...

and

b) Spree's `show` method also sets `@taxon`, which I'd really like to be able to use in my own  `get_related_products` method.

So, what I want is a hook like CakePHP's `before_render`, which gets called AFTER the controller method has run, but BEFORE the view is rendered. I can't seem to find a rails equivalent. Is there such a thing? `after_filter` won't do it for me, since that's called after the view is rendered.

And if not, what is the best way to kind of tack-on a call to `get_related_products` after the `show` method of Spree's products controller has run, in a way that I can get it's instance variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Spree's **load_product** will always be called before your **get_related_products** as it is registered before.

b) There's no **before_render** and no filter between **before_filter** and **after_filter**.

You can achieve this by overwriting **:render**:

```
class Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do
    def render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
      # here you define related products
      @related_products = search_related_products(@product)

      # don't forget to call super
      super(options, extra_options, &block)
    end
end
```

Comment: This answer could be cleaner: def render(*args) run_before_render and super end